# Deadlock in goroutine with GopherJS

Tags: go, deadlock, gopherjs

Why is there a deadlock in the following code? I am trying to return something from the goroutine to outside

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
    "time"
)

func test(this js.Value, i []js.Value) interface{} {
    done := make(chan string, 1)

    go func() {
        doRequest := func(this js.Value, i []js.Value) interface{} {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)

            return 0
        }

        js.Global().Set("doRequest", js.FuncOf(doRequest))
        args := []js.Value{js.ValueOf("url")}
        var x js.Value
        doRequest(x, args)
        done <- "true"
    }()

    aa := <-done
    fmt.Println(aa)

    return 0
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    js.Global().Set("test", js.FuncOf(test))
    <-c
}
```

When I run this on a browser and call test(),  the following error will be shown

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what it says in the error message.  All goroutines are asleep.  `main` doesn't start anything and just does a channel receive, so it's blocked, and no other goroutines are running, so there's no possibility that `main` could ever wake up again, so the runtime panics.

If I recall correctly, unlike regular Go, GopherJS doesn't shut everything down and exit if `main` exits (in part because: what exactly would that even mean?  The closest analog to a Go program would be to close the webpage!  Which would kind of suck.  So GopherJS doesn't do that.).  So what you're doing to keep `main` alive is not necessary, strictly speaking, in GopherJS.

That said, if you say (for example) `time.Sleep(time.Hour)` at the end instead, then while all goroutines are still asleep (strictly speaking), `main` will eventually wake up, which the runtime knows, so it doesn't panic in that case.

As to your actual `test` function, once you do try it, you get a related error message: `Uncaught Error: runtime error: cannot block in JavaScript callback, fix by wrapping code in goroutine`.  `test` does a blocking call on a channel, and GopherJS won't allow that in a function called directly from Javascript, so it panics.  (When I run it in the [playground](https://gopherjs.github.io/playground/#/qOxhBk2d_U), I also get `Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function`, but that's just fallout from the earlier error.) 
 I *think* what you're trying to do is wait for `doRequest` to finish, print the value, and return, but that won't work.  You'll need to use a native Javascript promise, or some other asynchronous mechanism, for that.

Comment: Thanks it totally makes sense. I am trying to write the value to console with i.e ```js.Global().Get("console").Call("log", value.String())``` and it works. But when I try to send the value to a chrome extension, somehow I couldn't take the message with ```js.Global().Get("chrome").Get("runtime").Call("sendMessage", "extension_id", "Message:: "+value.String())``` But, I guess this is something for a different question. I will accept this answer.

Comment: @iesiyok An easier way to get `console.log` is just `println` — which is considered non-blocking, so it works fine.  Trying to send a message to an extension would be a blocking call (I assume), so, yeah, you're going to have to try something else for that.

Comment: I ended up with defining an object with ```js.Global().Set("anObject", obj)``` and using "anObject" in the background script after go part calls back the ```js.Global().Get("window").Call("assignedObjectCallback")``` after assigning the object. It works fine right now and I assume this is not blocking, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    js.Global().Set("test", js.FuncOf(test))
    <-c
}
```

You have made a channel `c`, and then wait to receive a value from it. Notice how `c` is a variable local to the `main` function. The reference to `c` is never passed anywhere else in the program, so there can never be a value sent on the `c` channel, and thus your main goroutine will wait forever to receive.